# Slice a string in groovy

Tags: java, string, groovy, substring, slice

I have a 18 character string I want characters 2-8 from.  In python I can do this:

```
sliceMe = "nnYYYYYYnnnnnnnnnn"
print sliceMe[2:8]
```

prints

```
YYYYYY
```

I am looking for a way to do this same thing in groovy, and every explanation is REALLY long.  Whats the elegant accepted way to do this in groovy (or java for that matter)?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

```
groovy:000> sliceMe = "nnYYYYYYnnnnnnnnnn"
===> nnYYYYYYnnnnnnnnnn
groovy:000> sliceMe[2..7]
===> YYYYYY
```

Note the difference in the length being 1 less.

Comment: Or `sliceMe[2..<8]` if you want provide the index of the first character to exclude like in python

Comment: `"abcz".[1..-1]` --> "**bcz**";  `"abcz".[1..-2]` --> "**bc**"

Comment: @Torbilicious  Negative indexes in string ranges start from the end.   Effectively, [1..-2] means "start at index 1, and go to the 2nd character starting at the last and going backwards"

Answer (score 8):

You inherit all the Java methods off `String` so `sliceMe.substring(2,7)` should do the trick.

Comment: Thankyou.  Learning groovy without having ever programmed java leads me down some funny roads.

Comment: That being the case, when you have a question about how to do something with an object in Groovy, you can always look at the object in java - the groovy object adds additional methods, but the java methods remain.

Comment: yeah my problem was bad googling cuz ya'll java people don't call it slicing :(

Answer (score 5):

For future reference, you can compare the "Programming Language Examples Alike Cookbook" strings methods if you are unclear on how something is written in Python versus Groovy (or other syntaxes).

Here are the slicing python strings http://pleac.sourceforge.net/pleac_python/strings.html

And here are the slicing groovy strings: http://pleac.sourceforge.net/pleac_groovy/strings.html

Check the table of contents if you need to see other comparisons, its a good reference.

Comment: I prefer [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org). For string slicing see, http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Substring/Top_and_tail