# Python like list slicing in Groovy

Tags: python, groovy

Given the following list:

`a = [0,1,2,3,4,5]`

In python I can do this:

`a[2:4]` which will get me `[2,3]`

Given that same list in groovy, is there a similar slicing mechanism I can use?

Comment: I believe this should suit your needs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998410/slice-a-string-in-groovy

Comment: yup gonna put it as the answer

Comment: If you want to slice till the end. a[start_index..-1]

Answer (score 20):

The answer is:

`a[2..3]`

another example would be if you wanted [1,2,3,4]:

`a[1..4]`

Comment: If you really want the *half-open* range, like in Python, You can always do this: `a[2..<4]`. This syntax has the advantage of allowing you to specify a *zero-length* sublist, like this: `a[2..<2]`. There is no way to make a *zero-length* sublist using inclusive range syntax.

Comment: @BalRog A better way to do half-open range is to use `-1` as in `a[2..-1]` as you don't need to know the length.

Comment: @haridsv That is only if you are going to the end of the list. If you are trying to isolate an *interior* sublist, like the OP, this will not have the intended effect. Furthermore, your list is NOT half-open since it explicitly INCLUDES element "-1", the the last element of the list.

Comment: @BalRog I had a wrong impression of what half-open meant, thanks for pointing out my mistake.

Comment: @haridsv it's all good :). For the record _open_ and _closed_ here are used in the sense of mathematical interval notation. The math notation/terminology _open_ interval `(50,100)` would contain all points between 50 and 100 _excluding_ the endpoints. The _closed_ interval `[50,100]` would contain all the points between 50 and 100 _including_ the endpoints. _Half-open_ could be either `(50,100]` or `[50,100)` (with obvious meaning in each case), although with C-based languages like Groovy we usually mean the latter of the two.

Comment: @BalRog Thanks for the explanation. I sort of figured that from your last response and then googled to confirm :)